# Downgrade from KDE 5 to KDE 4

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, kde, 15.04

How do you downgrade from KDE 5 to KDE 4 or downgrade from Kubuntu 15.04 to Kubuntu 14.10.

KDE 5 has been giving errors since I installed it, now I want to downgrade it.

Comment: There is no way to downgrade from plasma 5 (it is still KDE 4) nor is there any easy way of downgrading to 14.10. 15.04 is still in development, so file a bug report(s).

Comment: Sure-fire way is to backup your data, then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

You probably upgraded your system to KDE 5, so you can remove the repository from where you installed KDE 5 and do sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. this should work..

Comment: Tried that, did not work.

Comment: It is plasma 5, not KDE 5 ;) And there is no way to downgrade.

Comment: You could try this link - http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/09/kde-plasma-5-in-kubuntu-14-04-kubuntu-14-10-and-linux-mint-17-kde.html